# Azure-TFS deployment project making build fail

Tags: c#, azure, deployment, tfs, build

I have been publishing my web site using Azure-TFS continuous delivery for quite a while already, and it has been working great until now.

I broke it by adding a new Project (WPF) to my solution, in fact the build process try to compile the WPF application and end up with an error because it doesn't know one of the xmlns I use in my view (one of the dependency).

My asp project doesn't have any references to the WPF application (direct or indirect), yet TFS try to build it.

Is there a way to explicitly exclude files or projects from a TFS build definition ?

Thanks for your responses,

Adrien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building few projects by specifying a solution file in build definition and want to exclude a specific project in build?

In this scenario, you need to update them in solution file configuration properties itself.